# What does the setting "Standby intelligent power saving" do?

Tags: battery-life

I have purchased a new phone, Alcatel Pixi 4 (5") running on Marshmallow. It has enabled by default a setting called "Standby intelligent power saving" in the Battery settings, but I can't find (Google) an explanation of what this setting does.

What does the setting "Standby intelligent power saving" do?

Comment: Phone model please

Comment: Sounds like an extended/custom Doze mode. Read more about Doze here: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Answer (score 2):

All this does is turning off unnecessary stuff that runs in your background when your phone is locked.

This includes:

- Less notifications
- Restrict mobile data (not WiFi)
- Less waves transmitted by the device
- Shuts off location services

This of course helps to keep the device save battery when locked, though Alcatel Pixi 4 might not have the best battery.